# How do I properly deallocate memory allocated with a linked list?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which uses a linked list, and in my code I create an object pointer using the "new" keyword. From what I understand, any time you use the new keyword, you need to also have a delete, and I am wondering if I am doing this correctly.

```
#include"gameClass.h"
#include"card.h"
#include"list.h"
#include"node.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
}

List::~List()
{
    delete head;
}

void List::add(Card* tmpCard)
{
    if (head == NULL)
{
    Node* tmpNode;
    tmpNode = new Node;
    tmpNode->setNext(NULL);
    tmpNode->setData(tmpCard);
    head = tmpNode;
    delete tmpNode;
}
else
{
    Node* tmpNode;
    tmpNode = new Node;
    tmpNode->setNext(head->getNext());
    tmpNode->setData(tmpCard);
    head = tmpNode;
    delete tmpNode;
}
}

 Card * List::remove()
{
    if (head != NULL)
{
    //Card* tmpCard;
    Node* tmpNode;

    tmpNode = new Node;
    tmpNode->setNext(head->getNext());
    tmpNode->setData(head->getData());
    head->setNext(tmpNode->getNext());
    delete tmpNode;
}
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Install new `head` and delete it immediately?? Too bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it completely wrongly.

- You are introducing a new `head` and then `delete` the new `head` immediately. It is very bad.
- Your `remove()` function does virtually nothing. It create a new `Node`, set some parameter to it, then retrieve the data set which is supposed to same, and `delete` the new `Node`.

Try this:

```
#include"gameClass.h"
#include"card.h"
#include"list.h"
#include"node.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
}

List::~List()
{
    // delete all node currently have instead of only head
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        Node* tmpNode = head;
        delete head;
        head = tmpNode;
    }
}

void List::add(Card* tmpCard)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        Node* tmpNode;
        tmpNode = new Node;
        tmpNode->setNext(NULL);
        tmpNode->setData(tmpCard);
        head = tmpNode;
        // do not delete the new node here!
    }
    else
    {
        Node* tmpNode;
        tmpNode = new Node;
        tmpNode->setNext(head); // the new head should be linked to current head, not the next node of current head
        tmpNode->setData(tmpCard);
        head = tmpNode;
        // do not delete the new node here!
    }
}

 Card * List::remove()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        //Card* tmpCard;
        Node* tmpNode;

        // no creating new nodes to remove the first node
        tmpNode = head->getNext(); // remember where the next node is
        delete head; // remove the head
        head = tmpNode; // move the head
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to return the pointer to the card in the node to be removed, the `remove()` function will be like this:

```
 Card * List::remove()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        Card* tmpCard;
        Node* tmpNode;

        tmpCard = head->getData(); // remember where the card pointed by head is
        tmpNode = head->getNext(); // remember where the next node is
        delete head; // remove the head
        head = tmpNode; // move the head
        return tmpCard; // return the card
    }
    return nullptr; // there are no cards in this list
}
```

Comment: So, the remove was set up to return a card pointer so that I could put each removed card into another single linked list (FILO) in a random order. I created the new Node so I could return the pointer before it was deleted, was this the wrong way to do that task?

Comment: You want to return it? But you dudnlt return it. Also, you want to return a card pointer, so return a card pointer, not pointer to `Node` nor creating new `Node`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i followed your first example and ended up with your second example while figuring out how to return what i needed

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem, simply use a `std::shared_ptr<Node>`. The pointer will deallocate what it points to as soon as it goes out of scope (if no other shared pointer point to it).

If you do want to practice using new/delete, you misunderstood what it does: You create a new node using `new` and then work with that node in some fashion. Only when the node is no longer requried do you delete it. Right now the following happens:

```
Node* tmpNode;
tmpNode = new Node;        // You get a new Node on heap.
tmpNode->setNext(NULL);    
tmpNode->setData(tmpCard);
head = tmpNode;            // Head now points to the new Node. All is well.
delete tmpNode;            // The Node both tmpNode and head point to is deleted!
```

Now, both head and tmpNode contain a pointer to unallocated memory. When you access it you get undefined behaviour. What you probably want is to delete all nodes in the destructor of List and nowhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the comments in my code, this is very helpful!